# Convert PHP array to JavaScript array

Tags: php, javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a multi-dimensional PHP array to JavaScript and found this script in a post here;

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

But the JS array remains empty. Is it because I have a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Please show us a `var_dump` of your `$php_array`.

Comment: Is this dump ok?; array(20) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "106" ["question"]=> string(34) "The capital of Bosnia Herzegovina." ["alternative1"]=> string(8) "Sarajevo" ["alternative2"]=> string(8) "Brussels" ["alternative3"]=> string(5) "Minsk" ["alternative4"]=> string(6) "Vienna" }

Comment: Double check that `$php_array` isn't empty. If its not, then `$js_array` will not be either. :)

Comment: Which version of PHP? `json_encode()` is available from 5.2 onward. Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: The server has 5.2. I don't know if error reporting is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment you gave to one of the answers, are you sure `$js_array` is empty or are you just not decoding it? If you look at the generated JavaScript, do you see `var javascript_array = ;` or something else? Alternatively you could add `alert( javascript_array );` to check.

EDIT: Since the variable is ok, you can now access the elements with `javascript_array[0].id`, `javascript_array[0].question` etc.

Comment: In the generated JS is says;var javascript_array = [{"id":"152","question":"The capital of El Salvador.","alternative1":"San Salvador","alternative2":"Roseau","alternative3":"Havana","alternative4":null},{" etc but alert( javascript_array ); gives [object Object], [object Object} etc

Comment: Looks like you're good to go, then. Is the problem that you don't know how to access the elements in the object?

Comment: I guess that the problem then might be that I don't know how to access the elements in the object? Can you tell me how? I haven't downvoted anything.

Comment: @Fred: There is plenty of documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @Fred: I edited the answer, but it'd be good to read up on objects as Felix suggested.

Comment: Felix, Juhana, many thanks for your help! I feel like an idiot (thought I had it right with javascript_array[3][4]). I will read up on this;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something more manual like this:

```
<?php
// $phpArray= ...
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var jsArray = {};
  <?php foreach($phpArray as $key => $val){ ?>
      jsArray.<?php echo $key; ?> = "<?php echo $val; ?>";
  <?php } ?>
  console.log(jsArray);
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If `$php_array` isn't empty, try to...

```
var javascript_array = <?php echo $js_array; ?>;
```

...instead of:

```
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Still the same problem.. I'm using this to check javascript array;

Comment: 1) Doesn't respond to his problem and 2) wouldn't make any difference if it did.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<javascript_array.length;i++){
document.write("<b>javascript_array["+i+"] is </b>=>"+javascript_array[i]+"<br>");
}
alert (javascript_array[3][4]);  it just says 'jsquestions[0] is =>[object Object]'  and 'Undefined'

Comment: @Fred: So why do you say `javascript_array` is empty? Obviously `javascript_array[0]` has a value. You said yourself that it is a multidimensional array (actually it is an array of objects). The array contains **one** object at index `0`. Hence `javascript_array[3][4]` does not exist. If you, e.g. want the id, you can get it via `javascript_array[0].id`.

Answer (score -2):

You probably have to eval that json in order for it to be more than just a string in your JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm totally new at this. How do I 'eval' it?

Comment: There is JavaScript's function `eval()`, but its not related.